# TFS Build process hangs on any NPM command

Tags: tfs, angular, tfsbuild, angular-cli

I'm building an angular2 app, and I've developed a build profile in TFS to auto-build it.

There are four npm commands:

- `npm install angular-cli -g`
- `npm install`
- `npm run typings` (executes `typings install`)
- `npm run build` (executes `ng build`)

And then a `Copy Publish Artifact` step.

However, even when every step passes, it says `Finishing Copy and Publish Build Artifacts`, the project has been built, and the files have been moved, the actual build ***never finishes***.  I've tried breaking those npm commands into a powershell script, having them as `NPM` commands within TFS, and running them as `CMD` commands, but the same thing happens every time.  Also, if I just remote into the build server and run the commands by hand, it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: may be `npm install --verbose` can help during installation . also try `npm config ls -l` to check out your config settings

Comment: I was under the impression that `angular-cli` is not released yet. How can you run that command if the package is not there?

Comment: @candidJ The problem with verbose is that I can't run it side by side with --loglevel=error, and I need that loglevel because any warnings make TFS stop

Comment: @hani It's in beta, but it actually works pretty well.

Comment: @AlexKibler so you check-in the node_modules along with your source in order to do the TFS build?

Comment: @hani Nope, the second step of my build is to do an NPM install

Comment: @AlexKibler just noticed it in the OP. Another thing that bugs me is that you could run the commands manually, which remotely points to permission issues. The account that's used for remote login that you've mentioned, is it the same as the one for the build agent? Also check windows logs for warnings and errors.

Comment: @AlexKibler is your build process running as an administrator? Part of the angular-cli requires elevated privileges on Windows to create symlinks.

Comment: It is not, but I enabled symlinks for that user.  Let me be totally clear: The build is 100% working.  Everything is getting compiled and moved to where it needs to be.  The build just isn't "finishing"

Comment: Which one are you using vnext or xaml build? It seems related to the build agent. Did you try to run your build with another build agent ?

Answer (score 1):

We've gone through the same headache recently, and I'd strongly suggest you not rely on TFS Build to restore npm packages.  Even when you get that right, it takes long and doesn't deploy the node_modules you need to IIS.

Instead, use WebPack to bundle up your node_modules into a bundle.js.
Reference this in your projects/scripts folder and check it into source control.

Remove any npm install steps in your build process (it won't be required anymore since you're referencing the bundle.js now).

This will increase your quality (no future package version surprises), and speed up your deployment (no need to download npm packages on each build anymore).

It's fairly quick to get Webpack installed and you'll save yourself headaches :)